# Showing weak convergence of dirac measure using characteristic functions

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence, characteristic-functions

I want to show if $\mu_n=\frac{1}{n}\delta_n+(1-\frac{1}{n})\delta_0$ converges weakly using characteristic functions. I know that the characteristic function of $\delta_0$ is the constant function $1$. I also believe that $\phi_{\nu + \lambda}=\phi_\nu \phi_\lambda$ where $\phi$ always denotes the characteristic function respectively.

Firstly, I have the question if
$\phi_{a\lambda}(t)=\phi_\lambda(at) \ \forall a \ $  in the real numbers? If yes, my attempt is the following:

$\phi_{\frac{1}{n}\mu_n}(t)=\phi_{\delta_n}(\frac{1}{n}t)\ \phi_{\delta_0}(t) \ \phi_{\delta_0}(\frac{-1}{n}t)= \int e^{i(\frac{1}{n})tx}d\delta_n \cdot 1 \cdot 1 = e^{i \frac{1}{n}t n}=e^{it}=\int e^{itx} d\delta_1$

which would mean that $\mu_n \to \delta_1$ weakly. Is that correct? Thanks in advance!

(PS: This is my first question on stackexchange, so I would appreciate some feedback if I did anything wrong.)

Comment: $\phi_{a \mu} = a \phi_{\mu}$ obviously... Just write it out: $\phi_{\mu}(t) = \int e^{itx}\mu(dx)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition of the characteristic function, we have
$$
\varphi_{\mu_n}(t) = \int_{\mathbb R}e^{itx}\mu_n(\mathsf dx) = 1-\frac1n +\frac1n e^{int}.
$$
It follows that
$$
|\varphi_{\mu_n(t)}-1| = \frac1n|1-e^{int}|\leqslant \frac2n\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow 0,
$$
so that $\varphi_{\mu_n}\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow1$ and hence $\mu_n\stackrel d\rightarrow \delta_0$.